# Apply multiple filter on column using tuple

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, tuples

```
data = [['A',23], ['D',50], ['C',32], ['D',21], ['D',24], ['B',20], ['C',68], ['A',52], ['A',41],[ 'D',44], ['B',29], ['B',70], ['B',33], ['C',56], ['A',72]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['group', 'age'])
```

I would like to filter down to rows where  `age` is equal to, or between the ranges set out in the `group_mask` for each corresponding `group`

```
group_mask = {(20, 30): 'A', (25, 30): 'B', (65, 70): 'C', (40, 50): 'D'}
```

I am at a loss here as to how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
df['range'] = df['group'].map({v:k for k, v in group_mask.items()})
df['in_range'] = (df['range'].str[0] <= df['age'])  &  (df['age'] <= df['range'].str[1])

#filtered
df = df[df['in_range']]
df.drop(columns=['range', 'in_range'], inplace=True)

#   group   age
# 0 A   23
# 1 D   50
# 6 C   68
# 9 D   44
# 10    B   29
```

Comment: Yeah , applied the `drop` as per your edit also. All in all, your suggestion worked like a charm. `map` looks to be what i need to learn more about. Thanks